# Getting valid IP from IPHostEntry

Tags: c#, ip-address

I tried to get the IPAddress of my computer using this

```
        var ipadd = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ipAddress in ipadd.AddressList)
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address: {0}", ipAddress);
```

I have only one network card in my computer which is connected to the router. It is ipv4 but this line of code gives me 4 IPAddress 3 of them are ipv6 and one is ipv4 which is the valid one. I like to ask why is that so ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the IPV6 are invalid?

Comment: @kane, I dont know.. may be they are but I am on a ipv4 network. see this screenshot http://i51.tinypic.com/1zw0tv5.png

Comment: Do you want LAN or WAN address?

Comment: I am looking for the LAN ip.. 192.168.100.104

Comment: @geek, Yes.. I need that only.. also when I am connected to only one network then why it is showing up 4 ipaddresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (var addr in Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList)
{
    if (addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        Console.WriteLine("IPv4 Address: {0}", addr)
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works.. you are using "Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty)" and I have seen on other places that they use "Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());"... It doesn't matter if pass Dns.GetHostName() or not ?