# Getting local host Ip Address

Tags: c#, ip

```
public static string GetLocalIpAddress()
    {
        string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
        string IpAddress = Convert.ToString(ip.AddressList[2]);
        return IpAddress.ToString();
    }
```

This will some times show Index out of bound exception
what should be the problem in it.?
thanks in advance

Comment: ip.AddressList[2].You need to check how many elements are in the list.

Comment: Error occurs because the array index 2 > ip.AddressList.Length

Answer (score 7):

try this method, it works for me.

```
 public static string GetIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "?";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return localIP;
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var addr in Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList)
{
if (addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
Console.WriteLine("IPv4 Address: {0}", addr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As they have answering before. You should check your lenght on the AddressList. Becouse it will not always be 2.

Here you have another answer on stackoverflow:
[Getting valid IP from IPHostEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056838/getting-valid-ip-from-iphostentry)